# etcd "Not a directory" result when put some value

Tags: etcd

I'm using etcd v3.3 in my application and communicate with it over its WEB API.
According to [documentation](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/blob/master/Documentation/v2/api.md#creating-directories) I don't need to explicitly create directories when putting key-value pairs on some path.
Here is an example what I doing (note that the path /base-test-path/level1/level2/level3/ does not exist yet):

```
curl -X PUT -d value=foo http://localhost:2379/v2/keys/base-test-path/level1/level2/level3/
```

The result was:

```
{"action":"set","node":{"key":"/base-test-path/test/test/test","value":"foo","modifiedIndex":347017,"createdIndex":347017}}
```

But when I try to add a new value a bit deeper into existing path, I get an error  (note that the path /base-test-path/level1/level2/level3/ already exists because I run previous command before):

```
curl -X PUT -d value=foo http://localhost:2379/v2/keys/base-test-path/level1/level2/level3/level4
```

Response:

```
{"errorCode":104,"message":"Not a directory","cause":"/base-test-path/level1/level2/level3","index":347018}
```

It seems like etcd does not create directories when any part of the path already exists.

**The question is**: can I keep my code simple so I don't need to care about etcd directories and still be able to put values on every etcd's path I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like etcd, when speak it with API v2, can not create directories when some key is already on the place.
E.g. when you have a key

```
  /base-test-path/level1/somekey
```

You can not create such key ("Not a directory"):

```
 /base-test-path/level1/somekey/subkey
```

When I switched to API v3 this problem is eliminated as it does not have directories at all. [See a comment here](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/issues/6904#issuecomment-263337172) or official documentation [here](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/blob/master/Documentation/dev-guide/interacting_v3.md).